# Determine whether this field is a gradient vector field

Tags: partial-derivative, vector-fields

Let $n  \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $X \colon \mathbb{R}^2\backslash\{(0,0)\} \rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$ be the vector field
$$ X( x, y) = \begin{pmatrix}-y(x^2 + y^2)^n, x(x^2 + y^2)^n \end{pmatrix}.$$

a) For which  $n  \in \mathbb{Z}$ does there exist a function $f: \mathbb{R}^2\backslash\{(0,0)\} \rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ with $\nabla f(p)=X(p)$ for all p $\in \mathbb{R}^2\backslash\{(0,0)\}$?

b) For which  $n  \in \mathbb{Z}$ does a function $f: \mathbb{R}× \mathbb R_{> 0}\rightarrow\mathbb{R} $ with $\nabla f(p)=X(p)$ for all $p \in \mathbb{R}×\mathbb{R}_{>0}$ exist ?

Now for a) I came to the conclusion that it was only a gradient field for $n = 0$, since for $n  \ge |1|$ the chain rule would have been applied and there was no factor that when multiplied by the inner partial for $x  = -y$ and for $y  = x$, but for $n = 0$ everything in the parentheses  becomes a constant and so I can use the product rule.

Now for b) I was able to use the poincaré lemma and came to the conclusion that there was no $n$ for which $  \frac{\partial a}{\partial y} = \frac{\partial b}{\partial x} $ since
$$  \frac{\partial a}{\partial y} =  -(x^2 + y^2)^n - 2ny^2(x^2 + y^2)^{n-1}$$ and
$$  \frac{\partial a}{\partial y} =  (x^2 + y^2)^n + 2nx^2(x^2 + y^2)^{n-1}$$

For $0$ I get $-1$ and $1$. Now I'm not sure where I'm going wrong. I was already a bit hesitant on a) since it didn't seem very systematic and there are some weird integrals out there and then that the poincaré lemma contradicts my solution for a)... Have I missed something, got something wrong or misunderstood something? Is there a better way of doing this? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Huh? Try $n=0$ again, carefully. And there is an $n$ value that works in (b).

Comment: @TedShifrin are you saying that n=0 doesn't work? My idea was that $(x^2/2-y^2/2)(x^2+y^2)^0 should work. Also I'm drawing a blank on the n. Just don't see how to get around the minus sign

Comment: Just write $X=(-y,x)$. Is this a gradient?

Comment: @TedShifrin ah I see. Do you have a suggestion on how I could go about finding a solution?

Comment: I don’t know what you mean. For starters. For what $n$ is $X$ locally a gradient?

Comment: @TedShifrin for n = -1

Comment: Ok, now think about parts (a) and (b).

Comment: @TedShifrin I think I got it. Thanks! As far as I can tell since on R^2\{(0,0)} the line integral of a circle with the center at (0,0) would not be 0, there is no n for a, and for b it's -1